# What is the Cox-Reid adjusted likelihood used for?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

In [Love *et al* 2014](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-014-0550-8) they use an adjusted likelihood function that I would like to understand better in terms of its use case (i.e. when might I wish to use it). They say:

> We then maximize the Cox-Reid adjusted likelihood of the dispersion, conditioned on the fitted values $\mu_{ij}^0$ from the initial fit, to obtain the gene-wise estimate $\alpha_{i}^{\text{gw}}$, i.e.,
> $$\alpha_{i}^{\text{gw}} = \arg \max_\alpha \ell_{\text{CR}} \left( \alpha; \vec{\mu}_i^0,\vec{K}_i \right)$$ with $$\begin{align}\ell_{\text{CR}} \left( \alpha; \vec{\mu}_i^0,\vec{K}_i \right) &= \ell(\alpha) - \frac{1}{2} \log (\det (X^t W X)) \\ \ell(\alpha) &= \sum_j \log f_{\text{NB}} (K_j; \mu_j, \alpha) \end{align}$$ where $f_{\text{NB}} (K_j; \mu_j, \alpha)$ is the probability mass function of the negative binomial distribution with mean $\mu$ and dispersion $\alpha$, and the second term provides the Cox-Reid bias adjustment.

What strikes me about the CR adjustment is the form $X^t W X$ which provides a certain amount of robustness to outliers in weighted least squares regression. Does this adjustment effectively improve the robustness of the likelihood function to outliers in a similar fashion? Or does it have some other purpose?

Comment: Here are some links that can be useful:
http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~pmcc/pubs/paper15.pdf ("A simple method for adjustment of profile likelihoods" by McCullagh & Tibshirani - see Introduction)
Also, here is the original Cox and Reid article: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/240166806_Parameter_orthogonality_and_approximate_conditional_inference_with_discussion ("Parameter orthogonality and approximate conditional inference (with discussion)").
Also you are welcome to check Wikipedia for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuisance_parameter